# Reduce runtime by simplifying a piece of code which I am using at many places in my solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization

I am trying to improve my code performance. I am using the following piece of code at multiple locations -

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

x = pd.DataFrame({'x':['id_1']*10,
                  'lag_01':[random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(10)],
                  'lag_02':[random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(10)]
                  })
x['p'] = [np.nan]*10
LAG_COLS = ['lag_01', 'lag_02']

## Part I want to optimize
for row_num, idx in x.iterrows():
    p = random.randint(70, 80)
    x.at[row_num, 'p'] = p
    
    i = row_num+1
    for lag in LAG_COLS:
        if i in x.index:
            x.at[i, lag] = p
            i = i + 1
```

The code updates the value of the lag columns for subsequent records with the value of 'p' which is calculated for each row. For example, for the following scenario -

[image]

The output would look like this -
step-1

[image]

step-2

[image]

How can I optimize this code?

Comment: Please provide all data as formatted text, and provide a [mcve]

Comment: What about putting this in a function or lambda?

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: Hi, I have added the minimum reproducible example. I want to reduce my runtime.

Comment: It looks like your code reimplements (slowly) the `DataFrame.shift` / `Series.shift` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html. As you discovered, `iterrows` is almost always the slowest possible thing you can do in a data frame. If you do need to iterate, `itertuples` is usually a better choice, not just for performance but also for "dtype-safety" (see the docs for `iterrows` for more info on this).

Comment: Essentially what @shadowtalker is saying - why not create `p` first and then create `lag_01` and `lag_02` with the `shift` method?

Comment: So `p` here is a forecast value which I am creating (should have been clearer, my bad!) and each time I would want to update my lag numbers based on the forecast I generated in previous time period.